# getting error to restore bak file in firebird?

Tags: database, firebird, ubuntu-server

While restoring .bak file on Ubuntu AWS server, I am getting an error "Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000 file /home/ubuntu/Backup.bak is not a valid database". Can anyone please help?

Comment: How was this backup created, and how are you trying to restore it? The error suggests you are not trying to restore it, but instead try to use the backup as a database.

Comment: It is automated back up from biometric system. and i am just trying to connect via command : CONNECT 'dbname.bak' user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'; Ihave connected the same file on my local machine.. The only problem is with aws server.... There also if i connect with my local customized db then i am able to connect but the only issue with the automated back up...

Comment: Then it seems it is not a backup, but a copy of the file. Since AWS is probably running a different OS, you need to perform a real backup and restore using the Firebird tool gbak.

Comment: But I should at least open the copy of the file.. which i can do on my local machine.. And the same file i have copied on AWS server also... and using the same way as a local machine... then why i am getting such result??

Comment: Because the database file is not transferable like this; if you can open it on your local machine it (usually) means that the database was created on the same platform (eg Windows). For older versions of Firebird there is also a difference depending on if you are using the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Firebird. If you want to transfer between different platforms, you have to use a real backup (in transportable format, which is the default).

Comment: As a side note: are you sure the privacy laws of your country allows you to transfer biometric information to a service hosted by an American company?

Comment: Database created on windows aws server. I copied it on my local ubuntu system. After that I have successfully opened the copy on my local ubuntu system. Same file I transfered to ubuntu aws server using scp command. Now I tried to open the same file using firebird (the same way as my local system). But here I am getting the issue "Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000 file /home/ubuntu/Backup.bak is not a valid database"

Comment: Please re-read my comments, one might be 32 bit and the other 64 bit (which is relevant if you have an older database format, ie ODS 10). Finally, if you copied the file while the database was still in use on your local machine might also cause problems. I repeat once again: create a backup with gbak on one machine and restore it on the other machine. That is the only guaranteed way to move a Firebird database.

Comment: As I told you, I can not create backup file manually. It is a automated backup from safescan biometric system. Kindly let me know how to restore this .bak file in firebird.

Comment: There is no other option; if you can't create a backup from the application directly, you should make one from your local machine (where you can open the database copy). Other than that, you would need to contact the vendor of your application and ask them to use the real method of backing up the Firebird database instead of just copying the database file.