# how to restore or connect a database of 32 bit system data on 64 bit system?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, firebird, 32bit-64bit, fdb

While connecting to a bak file using firebird on 64 bit Ubuntu system I am getting error as file is invalid. But may be it is because of bit issue of the system. Because I have connected the same database on my Ubuntu 32 bit system. So here what should I do? Is there any way to convert a 64 bit file on 32 bit machine.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you want to do.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and ask again - possibly on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I am trying connect to a database .bak file using firebird. All working perfect on 32 bit system. but when i try to connect the same database bak file on 64 bit system.. I am getting an error "filename.bak is not a valid database"

Comment: check command line of gbak tool.
-b for backup
-r for restore

Comment: getting same error for gbak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting error to restore bak file in firebird?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855521/getting-error-to-restore-bak-file-in-firebird)

Comment: As I already said on the other question: you need to create a real backup with gbak and restore that. You currently don't have a backup, just a copy of a Firebird database file (likely Firebird 1.5 or earlier, because afaik Firebird 2.0 (or maybe 2.1) no longer has a different structure for 32 bit and 64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

Create a backup on the 32-bit system using gbak -b -t (for transportable) and restore on the 64-bit system.

Comment: It is not necessary to specify `-t` as it is the default